# Laravel: add `stdout` stream for logging

Tags: php, laravel, logging, terminal, stdout

I want to add `stdout` stream for logging in conjunction with `storage/logs/laravel.log` file in my Laravel app.

So, I've added new `stdout` channel to `config/logging.php` file like this:

```php
'channels' => [

...

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'stdout' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stdout',
        ],
    ],

    'stderr' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stderr',
        ],
    ],

...

]
```

Is it correct? How can I monitor or check the work of `php://stdout`  or `php://stderr` streams of my app from terminal? Unfortunately, I can't find any reliable example yet.

Comment: Just tested this and stdout works just fine for me both for console commands as well as when using `php artisan serve`.  However as far as I can tell these are the only applications for this as `stdout` and `stderr` are only applicable in these contexts

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to this issue. But how did you monitor `stdout` result in terminal?

Comment: I used CLI commands locally so my terminal was open for the whole process